# Exit from a block of if statements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `nuxt.js` and javascript and I'm working on a form reCaptcha method and I have a series of `if statements` that I need to go through to proceed to the need block of conditions.

How can I best write this to exit this block at any stage and just error them out without having to write else (redirect error) every time?

Go through each block and if it fails just throw them out?

```
        if(sauhp.length < 1){
                //sauhp is empty and not a bot - proceed
                const token = await this.$recaptcha(formType);
                //Send the token to validate
                let verifyReCaptcha = await axios.get('/api/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='+secret+'&response='+token);
                let reCaptchaResponse = verifyReCaptcha.data;
                //Validate the action
                if(reCaptchaResponse.action === formType){
                    //Process the form
                    if(reCaptchaResponse.score > 1){
                        console.log('yes great go ahead')
                    }else{
                    window.$nuxt.error({ 
                            statusCode: 500, 
                            message: "We've detected a problem in the form submission. Call us, we're here to help."
                        }) 
                    }
                }
            }else{
                window.$nuxt.error({ 
                    statusCode: 500, 
                    message: "We've detected a problem in the form submission. Call us, we're here to help."
                })
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

`throw` an `Error` and `catch` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)) it outside the if:

```js
try {
  // your if block ... 
  throw new Error('error message');
  // ...
} catch (error) {
   window.$nuxt.error({ 
     statusCode: 500, 
     message: error.message
   });
}
```

of course, if you got the same error message, just hardcode it and simply `throw new Error();` or anything else for that matter

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your code like below

```
if(sauhp.length < 1){
                //sauhp is empty and not a bot - proceed
                const token = await this.$recaptcha(formType);
                //Send the token to validate
                let verifyReCaptcha = await axios.get('/api/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='+secret+'&response='+token);
                let reCaptchaResponse = verifyReCaptcha.data;
                //Validate the action
                if(reCaptchaResponse.action === formType && reCaptchaResponse.score > 1){
                    console.log('yes great go ahead')
                    return true;
                }
            }
            window.$nuxt.error({ 
                            statusCode: 500, 
                            message: "We've detected a problem in the form submission. Call us, we're here to help."
                        }) 
            }
        },
```